# Gnuplot conditional plotting: stringcolumn() function regarding dates

Tags: plot, conditional-statements, gnuplot

I have the following piece of data (example):

```
#Time      Data
07/22/2013 6286
07/22/2013 10695
07/22/2013 17868
07/22/2013 18880
07/22/2013 19206
07/22/2013 20365
07/22/2013 18459
07/11/2013 3420
07/11/2013 3256
```

I'd like to plot the date on the x-axis & the second column on the y-axis.

Under the condition it should only plot the rows where the date equals "07/22/2013".

this is what i tried:

```
set datafile separator " "
set xdata time
set timefmt "%m/%d/%Y"   
set xrange ["07/21/2013" : "07/23/2013"]
set yrange [3000:21000]  
set format x "%m/%d"
plot "test_date.txt" using (stringcolumn(1) eq "07/22/2013"? $1:1/0):2 w p title "spots" lc 7
```

As a result Gnuplot tries to plot the digram but no datapoints are set (seen in the following picture "Result")

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRqBm.png)

Does anyone know why that is? Do i should use "timecolumn()" instead of "stringcolumn()"? if so, how would i do this?

I'd appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is that `$1` tries to extract a number and will only find `07`. If you press the Autoscale button on the terminal window you will see that there is some data, but not where you expect it `"00:07"`.

A quick fix would be to replace `$1` with `timecolumn(1)`.
According to Ethan `set xdata time` is a relict from earlier gnuplot versions (but it still works). I would do it like the following:

**Code:**

```
### time data plot with ternary filter
reset session

$Data <<EOD
#Time      Data
07/22/2013 6286
07/22/2013 10695
07/22/2013 17868
07/22/2013 18880
07/22/2013 19206
07/22/2013 20365
07/22/2013 18459
07/11/2013 3420
07/11/2013 3256
EOD

myTimeFmt = "%m/%d/%Y"
set xrange[strptime(myTimeFmt,"07/21/2013"):strptime(myTimeFmt,"07/23/2013")]
set yrange [3000:21000]  
set format x "%m/%d" time

plot $Data u (strcol(1) eq "07/22/2013" ? timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt):NaN):2 w p title "spots" lc 7
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: I replaced relevant code snippets by your suggestions. It works fine for me now, including the timecolumn thing! thank you so much